# How to simplify the equation of combination?

Tags: probability, notation, article-writing

If there are three random variables and three related thresholds, how to simplify the following expression by summation or multiply or other operators? Thank you.

$\mathbb{E}[f_1(\cdot)|H_1>\theta_1,H_2>\theta_2,H_3>\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1>\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_2(\cdot)|H_1\leq\theta_1,H_2>\theta_2,H_3>\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1\leq\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_3(\cdot)|H_1>\theta_1,H_2\leq\theta_2,H_3>\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1>\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2\leq\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_4(\cdot)|H_1>\theta_1,H_2>\theta_2,H_3\leq\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1>\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3\leq\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_5(\cdot)|H_1\leq\theta_1,H_2\leq\theta_2,H_3>\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1\leq\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2\leq\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_6(\cdot)|H_1\leq\theta_1,H_2>\theta_2,H_3\leq\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1\leq\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3\leq\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_7(\cdot)|H_1>\theta_1,H_2\leq\theta_2,H_3\leq\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1>\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2\leq\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3\leq\theta_3]+\mathbb{E}[f_8(\cdot)|H_1\leq\theta_1,H_2\leq\theta_2,H_3\leq\theta_3]\mathbb{P}[H_1\leq\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2\leq\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3\leq\theta_3]$

where $f_i(\cdot)$ is the function of $H_1, H_2$ and $H_3$ and them are different.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in either the 5th term or the 8th term?

Comment: If each are independent, and there is in fact a typo in the fifth term, you could notice that each of these eight events form a partition of your sample space and so the sum would equal one.  Else, you can approach as Dirk suggests, seemingly reaching the same conclusion.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I did not write my problem completely. I have corrected it and written it in detail again.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by factorization. For example for the first two terms: 
$\mathbb{P}[H_1>\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]+\mathbb{P}[H_1\leq\theta_1]\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]=(\mathbb{P}[H_1>\theta_1]+\mathbb{P}[H_1\leq\theta_1])\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3]=\mathbb{P}[H_2>\theta_2]\mathbb{P}[H_3>\theta_3].$

Comment: sorry, I have rewritten my question and I think that this problem cannot be simplified by this scheme since every $f(\cdot)$ is different.